# Angular 4, input value binding, doesn't change in UI

Tags: html, angular, typescript, data-binding

I'm having trouble binding input to a value in angular 4, for example `[value]="inputFrom"`. Sometimes it changes when I change inputFrom, other times it doesn't. How do I make the input always change when `inputFrom` change and not just sometimes?

Can you maybe suggest another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Let me explain more about what I'm trying to do. I have two inputs:

```
<input [value]="inputFrom" type="number" [min]="inputMin" [max]="inputMax" (focusout)="onInputFromChanged($event.target.value)" />
<input [value]="inputTo"   type="number" [min]="inputMin" [max]="inputMax" (focusout)="onInputToChanged($event.target.value)" />
```

I have `inputMin`, `inputMax` variables, that can be null. They indicate the min and max values for the range. If they're null, it means there's no min or max value.

I also have `inputFrom`  and `inputTo`, which are binded to the html inputs.

I call `onInputFromChanged` or `onInputToChanged` functions when the input loses focus.

**What I want to happen here** is to validate the input value, and if it's not valid, fill it with a valid value.

**What really happens** is that the functions (`onInputFromChanged` or `onInputToChanged`) are called, then `inputFrom` or `inputTo` are changed, but *in the browser*, most of the time, the old value is left.

```
export class AppComponent {
  inputMin = 100; // can be null
  inputMax = 200; // can be null
  inputFrom = 100;
  inputTo = 200;

  onInputFromChanged(valueStr: string): void {
    const value = Number(valueStr);
    if (this.inputMin != null && value < this.inputMin) {
      this.inputFrom = this.inputMin;
    }
  }

  onInputToChanged(valueStr: string): void {
    const value = Number(valueStr);
    if (this.inputMax != null && value > this.inputMax) {
      this.inputTo = this.inputMax;
    }
  }
}
```

Other things I tried:

- I tried using ngModel. It doesnt change the behavior.
- I tried adding `oninput="validity.valid||(value='');"` or `onfocusout="validity.valid||(value='');"` to my input element. But what I need is to put `inputMin` or `inputMax` into the value, not an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

It works when there changes in input value.

```
export class AppComponent {

inputMin = 100; 
inputMax = 200; 
inputFrom = 100;
inputTo = 200;

handleInputChange(valueStr: string) { 
    const value = Number(valueStr);
    if (this.inputMax != null && value > this.inputMax) {
        this.inputTo = this.inputMax;
    }
    if (this.inputMin != null && value < this.inputMin) {
        this.inputFrom = this.inputMin;
    }
} 
}

<input [ngModel]="inputFrom"   type="number" [min]="inputMin" [max]="inputMax" (change)="handleInputChange($event.target.value)" (ngModelChange)="inputFrom = $event" />

<input [ngModel]="inputTo"  type="number" [min]="inputMin" [max]="inputMax" (change)="handleInputChange($event.target.value)" (ngModelChange)="inputTo = $event"/>
```